# R version of PHP function isset

Tags: r

I often find `isset()` from `PHP` very helpful. Trying to create an `R` version of it, I came up with the following:

```
isset <- function(x){

  a <- try(x, silent = TRUE)
  return(!inherits(a, "try-error") && !is.null(a) && (length(a) != 1L || !is.na(a)))

}
```

It's made by 3 checks:

- Does the object exist?
- If the case, is `NULL`?
- If not, and is **not** a vector, is `NA`?

As written above `isset` is very slow:

1) Simple case, no need at all for `isset`

```
> microbenchmark(isset(NULL), isset(NA))
Unit: microseconds
        expr    min     lq median     uq   max neval
 isset(NULL) 11.867 12.509 12.830 13.310 62.54   100
   isset(NA) 12.829 13.471 14.112 14.433 22.45   100
```

2) More useful, but still doable with is.null()

```
> test_var <- list(a = 1)
> microbenchmark(isset(test_var$b))
Unit: microseconds
              expr    min    lq median     uq     max neval
 isset(test_var$b) 12.509 13.15 13.791 14.112 112.892   100
```

3) Here it does help, but it also gets very slow

```
> rm(test_var)
> microbenchmark(isset(test_var), isset(test_var$b), try(test_var$b, silent = TRUE))
Unit: microseconds
                           expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
                isset(test_var) 736.038 764.1015 780.4575 815.5755 1223.844   100
              isset(test_var$b) 737.001 764.7425 786.0700 815.0940  986.837   100
 try(test_var$b, silent = TRUE) 732.832 760.2525 779.3345 815.4155 1034.944   100
```

Almost all the time is spent by `try`.

**Q:** Considering that it needs to return `FALSE` in each of the 3 cases above, how would you re-write `isset` to make it at least twice faster?

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in `exists`:

```
isset <- function(x) {
  is_variable <- make.names(name <- deparse(substitute(x))) == name
  if (is_variable && !exists(name)) return(FALSE)
  !is.null(x) && (length(x) != 1L || !is.na(x))
}

# > microbenchmark(isset(test_var), isset(test_var$b))
# Unit: microseconds
#              expr    min      lq median      uq     max neval
# isset(test_var)   28.011 28.9115 29.278 29.6445  41.960   100
# isset(test_var$b) 47.656 49.1515 49.690 50.4170 137.049   100
```

Comment: This way it can't detect if `a$b` exists. where `a <- list(b=anything)`.  `isset(a$b)` gives FALSE

Comment: better and very fast thanks. But it fails in case you want to check for `test_var$b` and `test_var` does not exist.

Comment: There's an endless permutation of these sorts of values, which can only be captured fully by `tryCatch` and is most likely a Turing-complete problem. (For example, `some_function(a$b[[some_other_function('some_value')]]$etc)`). If you restrict to a class of expressions, like `a$b$c` etc. you can get slightly better by `gsub('\\$.*', '', name)` first.